# Programmatically set the current view on a mat-calendar (from mat-datepicker) object?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to make a 'persistent' month/year picker using angular material2- the catch is that I don't want a traditional datepicker, but just the calendar part, which will remain open at all times and display the chosen month.  I have the functionality more or less working, but the problem is that once you've chosen the month, the 'smart' calendar automatically changes the view to the day picker.

Current code:

HTML

```
<mat-calendar #monthPicker
              startView="year"
              (yearSelected)="yearChosen($event, date)"
              (monthSelected)="monthChosen($event, date, monthPicker)"
              [selected]="date"
></mat-calendar>
```

TS (relevant portions)

```
yearChosen(year : Date, date : Date){
 //(date is a reference to a class-level date variable, just holds the current value)
  date.setFullYear(year.getFullYear())
}

monthChosen(month: Date, dateObj : Date, calendar : MatCalendar<Date>){
  date.setMonth(month.getMonth());
  //SOME CODE TO MAKE CALENDAR NOT PROCEED TO THE DAY VIEW???
}
```

I've tried messing with the objects on the datepicker object, but nothing seems to have any effect:

- calendar.currentView = 'year'
- calendar._goToDateInView(date,'year')
- calendar.(yearView and monthView, various things)

Comment: check after selecting any class is added to the calendar or not. if yes then you need to remove it.

Comment: It's more than a class- the calendar component appears to use ngSwitch (or something similar) to swap out the displayed element entirely.  It goes from a <mat-year-view> to a <mat-month-view>.

Answer (score 7):

You can use startAt property:

```
 <mat-calendar class="month-calendar" [startAt]="selectedMonth"></mat-calendar>
```

Bind startAt with the Date object in component:

```
selectedMonth: Date;
```

Inject calendar component reference:

```
@ViewChild(MatCalendar, {static: false}) calendar: MatCalendar<Date>;
```

Then you can change month programatically and refresh datepicker:

```
this.selectedMonth.setMonth(this.selectedMonth.getMonth() + 1);
this.calendar.updateTodaysDate();
```

Comment: Wasn't expecting an answer after so long... I ended up displaying this in a different way for this project, since the datepicker was so difficult.  If I get time I'll try to recreate this situation so I can see if your answer helps (although it's been a whole year so they may well have added functionality by now), but my first impression is that this would at best lead to a quick 'flickering' behavior when it auto-switches to day mode and then gets forced back to month mode.

Comment: yeah mat-calendar is the best and worst on the market at the same time, best for look and feel, worst for integration, so many missing methods!

Comment: I have to disagree @danday74. After using ngx-bootstrap calendar for over a year, I must say that mat-calendar is a breath of fresh air. It's built in a way that is actually quite easy to customise for nearly anything that you might want to do

Comment: @goonerify I agree to disagree :) whilst mat-calendar is fine for simple solutions, when u want to do something more complex it gets painful - e.g. adding buttons to the calendar header - such a simple task but unnecessarily painful

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve @lukaszwrzaszcz answer.

You can change month programatically and refresh datepicker:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.viewDate && changes.viewDate.previousValue) {
      if (!dayjs(changes.viewDate.currentValue).isSame(dayjs(changes.viewDate.previousValue), 'month')) {
        this.selectedMonth.setMonth(changes.viewDate.currentValue.getMonth());
        this.matCalendar.updateTodaysDate();
      }
    }
  }
```